# How to Convert data from model class to list

Tags: model, asp.net-identity, selectlist

Does anybody know a way to convert data from a Identity Framework model class to a selectlist.

I would like to export all data from that certain model class, and copy that into a selectlist.

Can someone explain me how I can do this?

I already tried: https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/mvc/htmlhelper-dropdownlist-dropdownlistfor

I tried this code, but it only reads the pre-filled data from the enum. Ans I would like to fill the selectbox with data from the modelclass.

```
public class Student
{
    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    [Display(Name="Name")]
    public string StudentName { get; set; }
    public Gender StudentGender { get; set; }
}

public enum Gender
{
    Male,
    Female    
}

@using MyMVCApp.Models

@model Student

@Html.DropDownList("StudentGender", 
                    new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(Gender))),
                    "Select Gender",
                    new { @class = "form-control" })
```

This above does not fit my needs, because they are using data defined in a Enum, and not data from the model class itself.

Gr.

Comment: A code example would help to understand your case better.

Comment: @dmigo I just updated my question with an example